# How do you convert audio files (on the fly) to the browser?

Tags: php, linux, apache, audio, ffmpeg

I would like to be able to convert audio files to MP3 to the users browser on the fly. The software I am using is: Apache, PHP & FFMPEG on an ubuntu system. Here is the code I have so far:

```
<?php
     header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
     header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3");

     passthru('ffmpeg -i song.flac -v 0 -ab 320k -f mp3 -');
?>
```

With this code, only the first few seconds of the audio are converted, however, when I comment out the header functions, the audio file is completely converted but all binary data is passed through to the screen (instead of wrapped in the browsers mp3 player).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Don't you think this is somekind of unefficient? Why not convert the files ones, save them on the server and then deliever them?

Comment: 1. I have over 600 GB of audio files, it would be a waste of space to have the both the original and the files and the converted ones just for this project.

2. Some browsers will be on lower bandwidth connections and some higher, so that would mean I would need multiple copies of each file to store (even more wasted space)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well i fount the answer. You have to calculate the output stream's size and output the following header (before the audio stream output):

```
header("Content-Length: {$calculatedFileSize}");
```

Comment: How did you calculate the output streams size prior to the transcoding? Would this restrict you to constant bitrate files where you could calculate the size based on the bitrate and length?