# Streaming short sound files

Tags: encoding, audio, streaming

I have a script that generates wave files, based on user input.
I want to be able to stream those wave files online(not necessarily as wave files, they can be converted on the fly to mp3 or whatever). Preferably through a embedded flash streamer, but a html5 version would be good too.
The files are generally small, around 5 seconds long, and I'd like then to be stream multiple files in one session.

Does anyone know how I should go about implementing this?

Answer (score 1):

With such short audio clips I would not bother with a 'real' streaming technology, but **just serve them up via HTTP as static files** as quickly as the network connection will allow.  A quick look at my iTunes library indicates that a 5s 128kpbs 44kHz stereo file is between 120-250KB.  Almost small.  If you are talking about 32kbps mono, then maybe the sizes will be a mere 15-30KB.

Encoding on-the-fly may result in undesirable issues, like scaling *(CPU load from all those encoding jobs, some of which will be duplicate)*, latency *(setting up the encoding, the actual encoding)*, and you won't know the end file size [which can cause problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834223/calculating-filesize-of-a-response/1835344#1835344).  So, setting up a caching system may make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I use [wpaudioplayer](http://wpaudioplayer.com/standalone) to stream MP3s from my website ([Example](http://www.everydayfiction.com/features/podcast/)). It was originally made as a wordpress plugin but can be used as a standalone javascript.

I believe that it can play wave files as well as MP3s. If you do end up converting them before serving them I would suggest that you would